# Ограничнить отправку почты списком доменов, пользователей

Tags: postfix, email, linux

Добрый день,

Голову всю сломал уже. Вроде все верно, а что-то не работает.Имеем Postfix,

список user_list

```
/^user1@*/   OK/^user2@*/   OK/^user3@*/   OK/.*@*/ REJECT 5.4.3. Sorry..
```

список allow_urls

```
domain1.ru limited_classdomain2.ru limited_class
```

хочу чтобы только те, кто в списке user_list, отправляли почту только на allow_urls

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = limited_classlimited_class = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/border/user_list, rejectsmtpd_sender_restrictions =  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/border/allow_urls
```

ничерта не выходит.. уже менял местами, и что-только не делал.. либо шлет всем, либо вообще никто никуда..

Ай нид хелп )

Comment: а зачем тут это?    /.*@*/ REJECT 5.4.3. Sorry..там же ...er_list, *reject*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знающие люди подсказали в чем проблема. Немного перепутал.user_list

```
/^user1@*/   limited_class    
/^user2@*/   limited_class    
/^user3@*/   limited_class    
/.*@*/ REJECT 5.4.3. Sorry..
```

список allow_urls

```
domain1.ru OK    
domain2.ru OK
```

сам конфиг

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = limited_class
limited_class =  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/border/allow_urls reject   
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/border/user_list
```

Comment: ты так далеко пойдёшь )) никто не нужен, чтоб получать ответы